# swift 3 repeating random animation / memory optimizing

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift3, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I found this animation [here](http://mathewsanders.com/prototyping-iOS-iPhone-iPad-animations-in-swift/) and updated to swift 3. I'd like add stars instead of phishes but I cannot get exactly what I need.

When I call this func it starts showing, moving and cancelling the views, but the loop shows always the views at the beginning relative high in the window.

How could I call the func more then once authomatically, or generate always different high at each loop?

could someone give me som hint about memory / battery  best perform it?

```
func myAnimation()  {

        let numberOfFish = 4 //Int(self.numberOfFishSlider.value)

        for _ in 1...numberOfFish {

            // set up some constants for the animation
            let duration = 2.0
            let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear
            let myRepeat = UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat
            // randomly assign a delay of 0.9 to 1s
            let delay = TimeInterval(900 + arc4random_uniform(100)) / 1000

            // set up some constants for the fish
            let size : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(40))+20
            //            let yPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(200))+20
            let yPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(UInt32(totalHeigt)))+20

            // create the fish
            let fish = UIImageView()
            //            fish.image = UIImage(named: "blue-fish")
            fish.backgroundColor = .blue
            fish.frame = CGRect(x: 0-size, y: yPosition, width: size, height: size) //CGRectMake(0-size, yPosition, size, size)
            self.view.addSubview(fish)

            // define the animation
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: [options, myRepeat], animations: {

                // move the fish
                fish.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width, y: yPosition, width: size, height: size) //CGRectMake(320, yPosition, size, size)


            }, completion: { animationFinished in

                // remove the fish
                fish.removeFromSuperview()

            })
        }



        //end of func
    }
```

at now I'm testing

```
 func startTimer() {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(onTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }




    func onTick(timer:Timer){
        print("Fired \(self.times)")
        times += 1
        // call your function
        myAnimation()
        if times < 10 {  // set the next timer
            self.startTimer()
        }
    }
```